# OGR Field Types to FileGDB

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I am trying to convert from PostGIS to FileGDB using GDAL (ogr2ogr). One of my fields is an integer field and declared in PostGIS as an int4. However when I do a standard ogr2ogr export looking at the FileGDB the field comes out as a Long Integer. So I am trying to override the defaults using COLUMN_TYPES but I cannot seem to find a list of correct values to use.

```
ogr2ogr -f OpenFileGDB  Output.gdb PG:"dbname=x user=x password=x host=x port=x" -sql "SELECT * from table" -lco COLUMN_TYPES=featurecode=Int16
```

I have tried Short Integer, smallint, and lots of different things including OFSTInt16

Does anyone know where a definitive list of field types is?

Comment: "Long Integer" in FGDB ***is*** `int4` (long long/`int8` won't be supported until Pro 3.1/ArcGIS 11.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this test in the GDAL autotest suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_fgdb.py#L819

```
# Test all data types
...
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeSmallInteger", 12)
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeInteger", 3456)
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeSingle", 78.9)
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeDouble", 1.23)
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeDate", "2012/12/31 12:34:56")
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeString", "astr")
    feat.SetField(
        "esriFieldTypeGlobalID", "{12345678-9ABC-DEF0-1234-567890ABCDEF}"
    )  # This is ignored and value is generated by FileGDB SDK itself
    feat.SetField("esriFieldTypeGUID", "{12345678-9abc-DEF0-1234-567890ABCDEF}")
```

Comment: thanks @user30184. Looking at that I should be then trying to use the words SmallInteger how I get an error "Ignoring COLUMN_TYPES=featurecode=SmallInteger : SmallInteger not recognized"

Comment: Did you try `esriFieldTypeSmallInteger`?

Comment: No I didnt, but i should have done because that has worked, thank you so much, been going around in circles for hours.